# SQL Server is in yyyy-dd-mm format, and application send yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: sql, sql-server, configuration, date-format

When application tries to insert data using this query (yyyy/mm/dd):

```
INSERT INTO Inv_Dueno_Equipo (Cod_Usuario, Fecha_Inicio, Fecha_Termino, Codigo_Equipo)
VALUES (1, '2012/01/26', '2012/01/31', 1);
```

I get an error

> The conversion from data type varchar to datetime produced a value out of range.

But if I change query to (`yyyy/dd/mm`)

```
INSERT INTO Inv_Dueno_Equipo (Cod_Usuario, Fecha_Inicio, Fecha_Termino, Codigo_Equipo)
VALUES (1, '2012/26/01', '2012/31/01', 1);
```

data is inserted. How can I fix this, where configuration I need to change for `yyyy/mm/dd` format to work?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SQL Server doesn't store a `DateTime` in any string format - it's stored as an 8 byte numerical value.

The various settings (language, date format) only influence how the `DateTime` is shown to you in SQL Server Management Studio - or how it is parsed when you attempt to convert a string to a `DateTime`.

There are many formats supported by SQL Server - see the [MSDN Books Online on CAST and CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx). Most of those formats are **dependent** on what settings you have - therefore, these settings might work some times - and sometimes not.

The way to solve this is to use the (slightly adapted) **ISO-8601 date format** that is supported by SQL Server - this format works **always** - regardless of your SQL Server language and dateformat settings.

The [ISO-8601 format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180878.aspx) is supported by SQL Server comes in two flavors:

- `YYYYMMDD` for just dates (no time portion); note here: **no dashes!**, that's very important! `YYYY-MM-DD` is **NOT** independent of the dateformat settings in your SQL Server and will **NOT** work in all situations!

or:

- `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS` for dates and times - note here: this format *has* dashes (but they *can* be omitted), and a fixed `T` as delimiter between the date and time portion of your `DATETIME`.

This is valid for SQL Server 2000 and newer.

If you use SQL Server 2008 or newer and the `DATE` datatype (only `DATE` - **not** `DATETIME`!), then you can indeed also use the `YYYY-MM-DD` format and that will work, too, with any settings in your SQL Server.

Don't ask me why this whole topic is so tricky and somewhat confusing - that's just the way it is. But with the `YYYYMMDD` format, you should be fine for any version of SQL Server and for any language and dateformat setting in your SQL Server.

So for your concrete case, try using:

```
INSERT INTO Inv_Dueno_Equipo (Cod_Usuario,Fecha_Inicio,Fecha_Termino,Codigo_Equipo)
VALUES (1, '20120126', '20120131', 1);
```

and you should be fine with that.

Answer (score 0):

convert function

```
INSERT INTO Inv_Dueno_Equipo (Cod_Usuario,Fecha_Inicio,Fecha_Termino,Codigo_Equipo) VALUES (1,convert('2012/01/26',103),convert('2012/01/31',103),1);
```

Please see the http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp
link and use the style param as required.